# Apigee edge-message-processor Error while starting up

Tags: java, apigee

We are trying to deploy APIGEE in a 5 node model and all other components seems correct except  `edge-message-processor-4.50.00-0.0`
The configs are standard and stored in `/opt/apigee/edge-message-processor/conf`

The error shows as below

```
2023-02-03 07:19:04,028  main ERROR KERNEL.DEPLOYMENT - ServiceDeployer.startService() : ServiceDeployer.deploy() : Got a life cycle exception while starting service [MessageProcessorService, For input string: "/etc"] : {}
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "/etc"
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:569)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.security.Password.deobfuscate(Password.java:191)
        at com.apigee.messaging.configuration.MessageProcessorServiceImpl.getSslKeyPassword(MessageProcessorServiceImpl.java:618)
        at com.apigee.messaging.configuration.MessageProcessorServiceImpl.registerHttpServer(MessageProcessorServiceImpl.java:510)
        at com.apigee.messaging.configuration.MessageProcessorServiceImpl.start(MessageProcessorServiceImpl.java:271)
        at com.apigee.kernel.service.deployment.ServiceDeployer.startService(ServiceDeployer.java:210)
        at com.apigee.kernel.service.deployment.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:77)
        at com.apigee.kernel.MicroKernel.deployAll(MicroKernel.java:244)
        at com.apigee.kernel.MicroKernel.start(MicroKernel.java:157)
        at com.apigee.kernel.MicroKernel.start(MicroKernel.java:152)
        at com.apigee.kernel.MicroKernel.main(MicroKernel.java:101)
2023-02-03 07:19:04,032  main ERROR KERNEL - MicroKernel.deployAll() : MicroKernel.deployAll() : Error in deploying the deployment : MessageProcessorService
com.apigee.kernel.exceptions.spi.UncheckedException: Starting of Service MessageProcessorService failed unexpectedly
        at com.apigee.kernel.service.deployment.ServiceDeployer.getUncheckedException(ServiceDeployer.java:236)
        at com.apigee.kernel.service.deployment.ServiceDeployer.startService(ServiceDeployer.java:219)
        at com.apigee.kernel.service.deployment.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:77)
        at com.apigee.kernel.MicroKernel.deployAll(MicroKernel.java:244)
        at com.apigee.kernel.MicroKernel.start(MicroKernel.java:157)
        at com.apigee.kernel.MicroKernel.start(MicroKernel.java:152)
        at com.apigee.kernel.MicroKernel.main(MicroKernel.java:101)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "/etc"
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:569)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.security.Password.deobfuscate(Password.java:191)
        at com.apigee.messaging.configuration.MessageProcessorServiceImpl.getSslKeyPassword(MessageProcessorServiceImpl.java:618)
        at com.apigee.messaging.configuration.MessageProcessorServiceImpl.registerHttpServer(MessageProcessorServiceImpl.java:510)
        at com.apigee.messaging.configuration.MessageProcessorServiceImpl.start(MessageProcessorServiceImpl.java:271)
        at com.apigee.kernel.service.deployment.ServiceDeployer.startService(ServiceDeployer.java:210)
        ... 5 common frames omitted
2023-02-03 07:19:04,033  Thread-1 INFO  KERNEL - ShutdownHook.run() : ShutdownHook.run : System shutdown in progress...
```

Other info

```
>> echo $PATH
/usr/lib/jvm/jre/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/apigee/apigee-adminapi-4.50.00-0.0.604/bin:/opt/apigee/apigee-service/bin:/root/bin


>> cat /opt/apigee/etc/defaults.sh

JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre
export JAVA_HOME
PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH=8
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=ip-10-164-156-123.eu-west-1.compute.internal"
```

Anyone have seen similar errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above error shows the password is passed as a ""/etc" instead of a numerical value, the system is unable to parse it as an integer.

For the Message Processor service, SSL key password configuration is failing it is used as an integer. check the SSL key password configuration in the **/opt/apigee/edge-message-processor/conf** directory.

Comment: thank you. I did find in the same place and found that the password had bad character created to an UTF-8 issue